# Cannot assert element is an HTMLDivElement

Tags: cypress

I want to check the type of element found with an id. I'm using an asserton with `instanceof` matcher, but it's failing.

My test is as follows:

```js
cy.get('#calculated').should(($el) => {
  expect($el[0]).to.be.instanceof(HTMLDivElement)
})
```

My HTML is

```html
<div id="calculated">123.40</div>
```

Clearly the element is a `div`, so what is wrong with the assertion syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `instanceof` element depends internally on the window that creates the element.

When you use the following, you are using `HTMLDivElement` from the top-level window (the Cypress runner window).

```js
expect($el[0]).to.be.instanceof(HTMLDivElement)
```

But the element you are testing is created by the window inside the app iframe.

If you reference `HTMLDivElement` from that window, the assertion will pass

```js
cy.window().then(win => {      // app window

  cy.get('#calculated').should(($el) => {
    expect($el[0]).to.be.instanceof(win.HTMLDivElement)  // qualify the type with
                                                         // the window reference
  })
})
```